# Define mysql_user privileges on specific host - "Invalid privileges string: Invalid privileges specified"

Tags: ansible, yaml, mariadb

I'm working on a task that is supposed to authorize a specific IP address to connect remotely to a MySQL database.

Here is the YAML file of the role :

```yaml
- name: Change MariaDB password
  mysql_user:
    login_unix_socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    name: "{{ mysql_user }}"
    password: "{{ mysql_password }}"
    priv: 
      "*.*:{{ mysql_user }}@{{ hostvars['mariadb']['ansible_host'] }}"
    state: present
```

I get the following error :

````
fatal: [mariadb]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "invalid privileges string: Invalid privileges specified: frozenset({'MARIADB.IP'})"}```
````

Comment: I'd _guess_ you have one too many `{` in a jinja expression somewhere, since `{"alpha"}` is [python syntax for a set literal](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets), but since you chose not to show one tiny bit of troubleshooting that you've already done, who knows

Comment: [priv](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/mysql_user_module.html) should contain `"*.*:{priv}"`  where `{priv}` is the privilege required.

Comment: I changed the mysql user for 'root'@'%' and now it's working... I don't understand why.

To answer your question @mdaniel, here's what I already tried :
* Passing the same values hardcoded
* Splitting the two parts of the privileges : `"*.*": "user@host"`